# Javascript Dropdown Menu (Enjin)

Tags: javascript, html

I've been having some trouble with trying to accomplish what I want with JavaScript, and so I decided to come to StackOverflow for help;
Note: I am using Enjin, which is a CMS designed for gaming.

**What This Currently Does**

- Displays login/register to new users
- Displays profile and logout links to logged in users
- The links are right now under the "Hello *name*" and "Hello Guest" respectively

**What I want it to do**

- Display "Hello Guest" with a dropdown arrow nexto it, toggling it would display the login and register links
- Similiarly, the "Hello Name" with a dropdown arrow nexto it, toggling it would display the logout and profile link

Any ideas on where to start with this would be great, as I have no clue.
Thanks in advance!

**My code:**

```
$(function(){

var username=$('.user span.element_username').text();

if (username == ''){ 
$(".topHead_text").prepend("Hello Guest!<br> <a href=\"/login\">Login</a> or <a href=\"/login/do/register\">Register</a>");
}
else{
$(".topHead_text").append('<a href="/profile">').append('Hello </a>');
$(".topHead_text").append(username);
$(".topHead_text").append('<a href="/logout"><br>LOGOUT</a>');
$(".topHead_text").append('<a href="/profile">PROFILE</a>');
$('#enjin-bar .right .join-site a').appendTo($('.topHead_text'));
}
```

});

Comment: I'd really appreciate help with this..

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at W3Schools? Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) on creating dropdown menus. I think this is just what you're looking for.

Also, you only tagged javascript and html in your post, but you're also using JQuery. Using plain javascript to get it working is fine and might be simpler. If you want to convert it to JQuery though, you can easily transform it with a similar [JQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) from W3Schools.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I don't get it though. I just find examples and figure out how they work, especially for basics. So W3Schools works for that, doesn't it? Docs are also good, such as MDN, but I feel they're overkill sometimes, like in this scenario when a simple example works and when things just seem intuitive.

Comment: W3Schools is not associated not affiliated with W3C in anyway. Most people are misleaded not to mention a lot of their tutorials are outdated. There are far better resources than W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

This as a starting point.  Not too fancy and can be improved.  Try it out here:https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/odk9a9vv/  Note I know very little about enjin so you will have to work that in.

**Markup**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="greeting" href="#"><span class="name">My Account</span><span class="dropdownimage">&#x25bc;</span></a>
  <div class="submenu">
    <ul class="root">
      <li><a class="login" href="/login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a class="profile" href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contentcontainer">
  <div class="user">
    <span class="element_username">I am Harry</span>
  </div>
  <div class="topHead_text">
    Tophead Text
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var username = $('.user span.element_username').text();
  if (!username) {
    username = 'Hello Guest!';
    $('.login').text("Login").attr('href', '/login');
    $('.profile').text("Register").attr('href', '/login/do/register');
  }
  $(".greeting").data('ishidden', true).find('.name').text(username);
  $(".greeting").on('click', function() {
    var X = $(this).data('ishidden');
    $(".submenu").toggle(X);
    $(this).data('ishidden', !X);
  });
  //Mouse click on sub menu
  $(".submenu").on('mouseup', function() {
    return false;
  });
  //Mouse click on user link
  $(".greeting").mouseup(function() {
    return false;
  });
  //Document Click to hide menu
  $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".greeting").data('isshown', '');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.contentcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  top: 3em;
}

.dropdown {
  top: 1em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown * {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
}

.dropdownimage {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.75em;
  left: -1em;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 10em;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0.6em;
  padding: 3em 0 0.25em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.8em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

.dropdown li a {
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #155FB0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.greeting {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 110;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0.75em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: -0.75em 0 0 -0.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.root {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}
```